# Show returned info on html view after compare values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm feeding a list with information from an API. Then, i compare with `for` the date. This is my code:

```
function taffy(){
        var  d = new Date();
        $scope.day = d.getDate();
        $scope.month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        $scope.year = d.getFullYear();
        $scope.today = $scope.year + "-" + $scope.month + "-" + $scope.day + "T00:00:00";
    }

function getBackAll (){
           $http.get('/api/Invoice?')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.amadeus = data.data.Response;

                for(var i = 0; i< $scope.amadeus.length; i++){
                    if($scope.amadeus[i].ProgramPayDate === $scope.today && $scope.amadeus[i].StatusId === 3){
                        $scope.viroba = $scope.amadeus[i];
                        console.log($scope.viroba);
                    }
                }
                //console.log($scope.amadeus);
        });
    }
```

What i'm doing is get the values of "today", and it works. My problem comes when i try to show on my html view:

```
<table align="center">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{today}}</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Company: {{viroba.Name}} Total: ${{viroba.Total}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

If i have one value, it's ok, i show it, but, if i have more than one, only shows one. I need to pass an ng-repeat?

Can you help me, please?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Yes you need to use `ng-repeat`.

Comment: It seems `$scope.viroba` is object, not an array. `ng-repeat` only works with  array.

Comment: So, then, how can i show all the values? I'm in blank

Comment: Try it yourself following these links. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat, https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need  to do these changes:

```
function getBackAll (){
           $http.get('/api/Invoice?')
            .then(function(data){
                $scope.amadeus = data.data.Response;

                for(var i = 0; i< $scope.amadeus.length; i++){
                    if($scope.amadeus[i].ProgramPayDate === $scope.today && $scope.amadeus[i].StatusId === 3){
                        $scope.viroba = $scope.amadeus[i];//Here $scope.viroba is object. You can convert it to array.
                        console.log($scope.viroba);
                    }else {
                     $scope.viroba = $scope.amadeus;
                    }
                }
                //console.log($scope.amadeus);
        });
```

HTML:

```
<table align="center">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{{today}}</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th ng-repeat="viroba in viroba">Company: {{viroba.Name}} Total: ${{viroba.Total}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```